# VectorDrawable file blurry android

Tags: android, image

I am using a VectorDrawable file and then applying it on a large ImageView. 
The main problem is that it's becoming blurry. 
I can't find out why
Here is the code:
[image: My Layout For Recycler]

This is the screenshot.
[image: My Screenshot]

Here is the VectorDrawable file xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
    android:pathData="M9,16.2L4.8,12l-1.4,1.4L9,19 21,7l-1.4,-1.4L9,16.2z"
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Have you tried VectorDrawableCompat from support lib?

Comment: No I haven't. I just used it directly in the XML file as src

Comment: Does scaleType="matrix" helps in this situation?